# actionscript3 creating object inside function

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder, box2d

I've been trying to write a function to create a simple circle in Box2DFlash . but it keeps telling me that the object is null and I can't access it's properties here's the code:

```
    public var f1:b2Body;
    public var f2:b2Body;
    public function addACrate(fallingCrate:b2Body, positionX:Number,positionY:Number):void
    {
                var fallingBodyDef:b2BodyDef = new b2BodyDef();
                fallingBodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
                fallingBodyDef.position.Set(positionX/ratio,positionY/ratio);

                fallingCrate =_world.CreateBody(fallingBodyDef);

                var fallingCrateShape:b2CircleShape = new b2CircleShape();
                fallingCrateShape.SetRadius(10/ratio);

                var fixtureDef:b2FixtureDef = new b2FixtureDef();
                fixtureDef.shape = fallingCrateShape;
                fixtureDef.density = 0.7;
                fixtureDef.friction = 0.5;
                fixtureDef.restitution = 0.3;//bouncyness

                fallingCrate.CreateFixture(fixtureDef);

    }

    addACrate(f1,270,0);
    trace(f1.GetPosition().y);
```

and when I try to access the "y" property of my "f1" object it tells me that it's null . I'll be appreciated if someone can tell me what's wrong
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Either change the `addACrate()` function to return the `b2Body` instead of setting it, so your call is

```
f1 = this.addACrate( 270.0, 0.0 );
```

or, set `f1` directly in the function (instead of using the `fallingCrate` parameter).

Then it should work. It has to do with the way Flash passes references. When you pass an object to a function, you can change properties *inside* that object, but you can't make it point to a new object. In your example `fallingCrate` is essentially a local variable that is set to whatever object you pass in when you make the call to `addACrate`. In your line

```
fallingCrate = _world.CreateBody(fallingBodyDef);
```

`fallingCrate` is now a local variable pointing to a new object. As `fallingCrate` is local, it goes out of scope when you exit the function.

Answer (score 0):

well, you get a Null reference exception because you presumably haven't set the value of `f1` anywhere. Solutions to this are:

In the function, use `f1 =  fallingCrate;` at the end

or

Define the function as

```
public function addACrate(fallingCrate:b2Body, positionX:Number,positionY:Number):b2Body
```

and then call it as `f1 = addACrate(arguments);`

---EDIT---

You are sending a reference to the function, so it should work as intended if it weren't for this line:

```
fallingCrate =_world.CreateBody(fallingBodyDef);
```

This reassigns the value of fallingCrate, so fallingCrate no longer refers to the same object as f1.

The solutions mentioned above still apply :)